# how to make a JScrollpane around a box layout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, scrollbar

i am creating a software for my project and here is what i have done so far..
what i am trying to do is, i have a jpane witch is created using net beans and it is inside a scrollpane(witch is also add using netbeans) and dynamically i created set of jpanes and add those jpanes in to the jpane i created using netbean.now the scrollpane doesn't work..i cant figure out the reason please help me

this is what i did

```
 int size=(int)jSpinner1.getValue();
    a=new JPanel [size];
 nameoftext=new JLabel[size];
 name=new JTextField[size];
 but =new JButton[size];
 iamge=new JLabel[size];



 jPanel1.removeAll();


 for(int x=0;x<size;x++)
 {

     a[x]=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    jPanel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel1,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));//this is the jpanel i created using netbeans
     jPanel1.add(a[x]);

     a[x].setVisible(true);


 }


 for(int x=0;x<size;x++)
 {

     nameoftext[x]=new JLabel("enter name");
     nameoftext[x].setText("enter name");
     name[x]=new JTextField();
     name[x].setName("name"+String.valueOf(x));
     name[x].setColumns(20);
     a[x].add(nameoftext[x]).setVisible(true);
     a[x].add(name[x]).setVisible(true);


 }
```

and there is one more thing i have to drag the border of jframe to make these components visible.. how to add them instantly to the jframe without dragging the frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add (or remove) components from a visible GUI you need to revalidate() the panel to invoke the layout manager so components can be given a proper size (and location), otherwise the size is (0, 0) and there is nothing to paint.

The basic code would be:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```